# Docker container restart instantly, despite I have set the "-t" °timeout° option

Tags: docker, containers

here my snippet:

```
docker restart -t 5 waitforit_
```

then docker ps returns immediately :

> status => run since 1s

How it is possible?
any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe `docker restart` is equivalent to `docker stop; docker start`.  The `-t` option isn’t a hard wait.  Rather, it says that if the process doesn’t stop on its own after receiving `SIGTERM`, then send it `SIGQUIT` (`kill -9`) after that many seconds.

If your process is well-behaved and exits promptly when it receives `SIGTERM`, then `docker restart` will in fact be pretty quick, regardless of whatever value you pass as `-t`.